# About soundcloud.com

Tags: audio, cloud, cloud-storage, audio-streaming

If I upload some sound to my account on soundcloud and copyright holder don't allow to download their music for free... What next?

The sound will be deleted?

Like these new music albums that I buy from Itunes or something else, if I will uploaded the album/sound that I bought legally, then it will be deleted from soundcloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference [Your Content](https://soundcloud.com/terms-of-use#your-content)

> Any and all audio, text, photos, pictures, graphics, comments, and
>   other content, data or information that you upload, store, transmit,
>   submit, exchange or make available to or via the Platform (hereinafter
>   "Your Content") is generated, owned and controlled solely by you, and
>   not by SoundCloud.
>
> SoundCloud does not claim any ownership rights in Your Content, and
>   you hereby expressly acknowledge and agree that Your Content remains
>   your sole responsibility.
>
> Without prejudice to the conditions set forth in Your Use of the
>   Platform you must not upload, store, distribute, send, transmit,
>   display, perform, make available or otherwise communicate to the
>   public any Content to which you do not hold the necessary rights. In
>   particular, any unauthorized use of copyright protected material
>   within Your Content (including by way of reproduction, distribution,
>   modification, adaptation, public display, public performance,
>   preparation of derivative works, making available or otherwise
>   communicating to the public via the Platform) may constitute an
>   infringement of third party rights and is strictly prohibited. Any
>   such infringements may result in termination of your access to the
>   Platform as described in the Repeat Infringers section below, and may
>   also result in civil litigation or criminal prosecution by or on
>   behalf of the relevant rightsholder.

**This is very clear. Don't upload content that doesn't belong to you. There could be big penalties.**